# getgrouplist behaviour in Single Sign-on using (GSSAPI) vs Username/Password login via PAM

Tags: c, redhat, kerberos, pam, gssapi

I have a program(C, Redhat) which lets the user login using **Single Sign-on via** **GSSAPI/(Kerberos)** or **username/password** via **PAM**.
After the login the user groups are fetched from **Active Directory** using **getgrouplist** function.

Now if I change the user groups in Active Directory (add a new group or remove an existing one), and user logins using **GSSAPI(kerberos)**, the group change is not reflected immediately i.e. the getgrouplist function returns the same group list returned in the previous login.

On the contrary, when user logins using **username/password via PAM**, the function getgrouplist always returns the latest group list.

I guess that some sort of caching is done (do not know where) and that cache is refreshed when user logins using username/password.

How can I force getgrouplist/Linux to always fetch the latest group list?

Comment: Linux is not "magically" bound to Active Directory. Check your SSSD configuration. Or maybe a commercial alternative such as Centrify.

Comment: Also, Kerberos / GSSAPI do not care about groups, authorizations, etc -- it's purely an authentication mechanism. Linux needs another round-trip via LDAP to get user's groups.

Comment: I guess your PAM auth uses LDAP for both authn & authz, at the same time; that would explain why it bypasses the SSSD cache.

Comment: No LDAP is not being used.

Comment: "I have a program(C, Redhat) which lets the user login using Single Sign-on via GSSAPI/(Kerberos) " - is this a custom program you wrote?  Let's see the relevant code.